# Applying for Schengen visa from UK with 1 month's bank statement

Tags: uk-residents, schengen-visas

I am a non-UK citizen working in the UK as a doctor. In two weeks, I plan to travel to Amsterdam for couple of days.

As the visa requirement states, one needs to provide 3 months of bank statements; I have been here just for a month now. I understand bank statements are just a part of the application but some answers here suggest that the application is likely to be refused if there are less than 3 months of statements included.

Would that be the sole reason for a refusal?

I have:

- current salary account with my first paycheck in it.
- previous travel to Spain, Germany and Switzerland, under my previous and first Schengen multi visa applied from home country.
- travel history as tourist of several countries around Asia and UK.
- hotel and tickets will be prepaid.

Comment: @Gayot Fow well that's the only consecutive 4 days off ( enough to visit another city/country) I will have in my next 8 weeks Rota.

Comment: I would say it depends. In my experience the Schengen countries tend to be quite dogmatic with submitting all the required documents for the application. Your explanation and circumstances makes sense. I do recollect I obtained a Schengen visa from the Spanish embassy in October last year with only my most recent bank statement of one month. Looking at your travel profile and profession, I would venture to say the odds are in your favor.

Comment: Assuming that you had a bank account somewhere else before moving to the UK, is there some reason you can't provide statements from this as well as your new UK account?

Comment: @djr as per Netherlands visa office, bank statements from outside UK must be original and less than a month old. I contacted my bank back home regarding that and was told that it will take at least 15 working days for me to receive it via post.